# How to republish events from event log?

Tags: event-sourcing

I see the notion of "republishing" events from event long mentioned everywhere, but it's not really described in detail.

The problem I am thinking of is the following. Certain Producer maintains an event log, and publishes every event to the Queue. Consumer connects to the queue and receives all the events produced.

Consider a case where there are two consumers (C1, C2) and one producer (P1).

Let's say that:

1. Producer P1 is started
2. Consumer C1 connects to the queue
3. P1 produces events E1, E2, E3
4. C1 consumes E1, E2, E3
5. Consumer C2 connects to the queue
6. P1 produces E4, E5, E6
7. C1 consumes E4, E5, E6
8. C2 consumes E4, E5, E6

At this point C2 has missed all events that previously happened! How does:

- C2 request the events E1, E2, E3 be republished?
- C2 avoid getting events out of order (i.e.getting E4 before getting E1, E2, E3)?

If anyone has some insights, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am thinking.

### Synchronizing Consumers with Producer

1. Consumer records last event sequence number received from a foreign context.

   - Records it in the aggregate table in the `latest_event_per_context` column (this only works for one foreign context) OR
   - Context relation that has a foreign key to aggregate table: `Table(aggregate_id, context_name, sequence_number)`, where the sequence number is the latest event received in a given context.
     This leaves this concern in application layer. OR
   - Records it as an event `EventReceived(event, context)` - leaves it to domain to discard duplicates
2. Producer sequences all the events it sends out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://geteventstore.com/
When a new subscriber is connected it has the ability to replay a stream.  GES offloads the duty of managing what has already been received to the clients.